# Как запустить node.js и apache(php) на одном порту?

Tags: php, node.js, чат, port, chat

Я хочу сделать чат на сокетах с помощью Node.js на apache. Возникла проблема, что ноду и апач нельзя запустить на одном порте. Если запускаю на разных, то, естественно, node просто не отлавливает событие и не присылает данные клиенту. Нужно или чтоб они могли взаимодействовать на разных портах или запустить node на одном порту с apache. Я может и некорректо вопрос поставил, но думаю вы поймёте.
Вот код, если это поможет.
Сервер:

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
      });
    });

    http.listen(8081, function(){
      console.log('listening on:8081');
    });
```

Клиент:

```
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
      $('#form').submit(function(){
        if($('#sendMassage').val() != ''){
          socket.emit( 'chat message', $('#sendMassage').val() );
          $('#sendMassage').val('');
          return false;
      }else{
          return false;
      }
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('.chat ul').append("<li class='<?php echo $visitor ?>'>" + text(msg) + "</li>");
      var div = $(".chat");
      div.scrollTop(div.prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
  });
```

Comment: Так запустите на разных портах, а на клиенте при коннекте укажите нужный: `socket.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');`.

Comment: либо юзаните nginx в качестве proxy / static сервера, повесьте один порт и по location разделите `/` на apache или php-fpm, а `/socket` на nodejs, при этом указав в apache и node разные порты

Comment: `var socket = io();
socket.connect('https://php-justrelaxdc.c9users.io:8081');` Cервер Node.js работает на 8081, поэтому указал его и адрес сайта, но всё равно почему-то не работает, хотя кажется это то, что нужно.